# Configuração de headers

Tags: c, c++, header, gcc

Estou tentando compilar alguns códigos em "C" via GCC (Derbian - Kali Linux), e ao compilar, recebo mensagens de erro dizendo que arquivos como `linux/linkage.h` e `asm/linkage.h` não foram encontrados. Ao emitir o comando locate linkage.h, verifiquei que tais arquivos estão em um diretório diferente do diretório padrão. Esses arquivos estão na pasta `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-common/include/linux/linkage.h` e `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-common/include/asm/linkage.h`

Como faço para o GCC considerar esses diretórios ao invés do diretórios padrão?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

O ideal seria os arquivos estarem nos locais onde o compilador busca.

Caso isto não seja possível utilize a [diretiva de compilação `I`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) e indique onde estão os arquivo de inclusão.

```
-I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-common/include/linux/
-I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-common/include/asm/
```